# Conditionally check if page is using template from plugin directory

Tags: plugin-development, page-template

I am having trouble loading the script conditionally in my plugin.

I have a DataTables page and want to load datatables scripts only for that page. So I made a page template called `datatables-template.php` and loading dynamically so can set the template in page attribute.

> **The template path** is
>   `my-plugin/public/templates/datatables-template.php`

So far so all is working fine. However, when I try to load script explicit fore that template using `is_page_template()`

When I have checked with `get_page_template()` that returning theme current page template which is `page.php` in my case.

**Note:** `is_page` working fine, of course, since it will check the current page, that would work. I have also checked my path using `file_exists` and that returns true. That means I am giving a correct path for the template. So no idea how to check it.

Additionally: I have tried with `global $template` which returns the correct plugin template but that doesn't work in conditional check in my plugin file.

```
global $template;

if('datatables-template.php' == $template){
    //load script
}
```

**Question:** How can I check if the page has set the specific page template in page attributes, in my case `datatables-template.php` and load script explicit for that page?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you would like to check your template right before loading.

I think the hook [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) is the best place you could do it.
Because this is the last place to load the template in loading procedure.

Regardless plugin or themes functions.php, it will also work.

The following is proved to be working in theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'q364016_check_template' );
function q364016_check_template( $template ) {
    // your code

    return $template;
}
```